# When praying in Jamaah, what should I do if I am the only one in the last row?

Tags: sharia, salat, jamaat

Asslamu allikum,

When praying in jamaah (congregation/group), I happened to be the only one in the last row. What do I do? Do I have to usher some one to step back and be with me?

Jazakallahu khayr.

Answer (score 4):

No, you shouldn't usher anybody. This will result in a gap in his row because, which is contradictory to what the prophet said:

> Ibn 'Umar (May Allah be pleased with them) reported:
>
> The Messenger of Allah (pbuh) said, "Arrange the rows in order, stand
>   shoulder to shoulder, close the gaps, be accommodating to your
>   brothers, and do not leave gaps for Satan. Whoever joins up a row, he
>   will be joined to Allah (i.e., to the Mercy of Allah); and whoever
>   cuts off a row, he will be cut off from Allah (i.e., from His Mercy)."
>
> [Abu Dawud].
>
> وعن ابن عمر رضي الله عنهما، أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏
>   "‏أقيموا الصفوف، وحاذوا المناكب، وسدوا الخلل، ولينوا بأيدي إخوانكم،
>   ولا تذروا فرجات للشيطان، ومن وصل صفًا وصله الله، ومن قطع صفًا قطعه
>   الله‏"‏‏.‏ ‏(‏‏(‏رواه أبو داود بإسناد صحيح‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏
>
> [Riyad as-Salihin](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/101)

Only if there were Imam and one person praying beside him (on his right side with a slight backprayer), then you will have to usher him if you want to pray with them so that both of you will make a row behind Imam, else you should try to fill a gap in the last row, if there is no gap, then just start a new row (by standing in the middle so the Imam is strait in front of you) and join the prayer:

- If someone came and stood with you in the new row, then that's done it.
- If none came, then you should re-pray the salat.

The Hadith says:

> "A man prayed alone behind the row s the Prophet ordered him to repeat
>   the Salat." (Sahih)
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ بَشَّارٍ، حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ
>   جَعْفَرٍ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ مُرَّةَ، عَنْ هِلاَلِ
>   بْنِ يِسَافٍ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ رَاشِدٍ، عَنْ وَابِصَةَ بْنِ مَعْبَدٍ،
>   أَنَّ رَجُلاً، صَلَّى خَلْفَ الصَّفِّ وَحْدَهُ فَأَمَرَهُ النَّبِيُّ
>   صلى الله عليه وسلم أَنْ يُعِيدَ الصَّلاَةَ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى
>   وَسَمِعْتُ الْجَارُودَ يَقُولُ سَمِعْتُ وَكِيعًا يَقُولُ إِذَا صَلَّى
>   الرَّجُلُ خَلْفَ الصَّفِّ وَحْدَهُ فَإِنَّهُ يُعِيدُ ‏.‏
>
> [Jami' Al-Tirmithi](http://sunnah.com/urn/702310)

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Jazakallahu haira .As per my knowledge you can can usher the middle person.and hence he will step backwards and join you in the new row.I was looking for the authentic versus for this.

Comment: @pckabeer: Answer updated, re-read it :)

Comment: @pckabeer to answer that we'd need to draw on hadith about valid reasons to distract someone during prayer.